# Vuex importing an undefined store

Tags: vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, vuex

I have an App component like this one:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="layout"></component>
  </div>
</template>
```

`layout` looks like this:

```js
computed: {
  layout() {
    return this.$route.meta.layout;
  }
},
```

One of those routes looks like this:

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '/login', component: Login, name: 'login', meta: { layout: 'without-login-layout'} },
]
```

So depending on the route, one or another component is loaded.

**The problem:**

In one of those dynamically created components, I have to call to a service, so I import it:

```js
import imagesService from '@/Services/imagesService';
```

That service depends on another service:

```js
import base from "@/Services/configService";
```

And that last one needs stuff from Vuex:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { router } from '../main.js'
import { store } from '../Store'

console.log(store);
```

For some reason, that `console.log(store)` prints `undefined`, but if I import the store in the first service:

```js
import { store } from '../Store';
import base from "@/Services/configService";
```

Everything works. I don't know what's going on. If, for example, I change that last import to lowecase, I mean:

```js
import { store } from '../store';
import base from "@/Services/configService";
```

It doesn't work, despite I'm on Windows. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:** Here's the code of `Store`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import { global } from "./global.module";
import { layout } from "./layout.module";
import { authentication } from "./authentication.module";
import { notifications } from "./notifications.module";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    global,
    layout,
    authentication,
    notifications,
  }
});
```

And here's one of the modules, the rest are very similar:

```js
export const notifications = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    notification: ""
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_NOTIFICATION(state, newNotification) {
      state.notification = newNotification;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: can you show a Store code?

Comment: @Anatoly I just updated the question with the store code.

Comment: Did you check othe places where you do `import { store } from '../Store'`? For instance where you register `store` in Vue?